# Migrate 1.9.* CE to 2.1.3 - field mapping

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

I have got the error message:

> Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields: imported,onestepcheckout_order_comment,onestepcheckout_giftwrap_amount

Then I have added to

> vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/map.xml

these rules

```
    <source>
         <field_rules>
          ...
<ignore>
   <field>sales_flat_order_imported</field>
</ignore>

<ignore>
   <field>sales_flat_order_onestepcheckout_order_comment</field>
</ignore>

<ignore>
   <field>sales_flat_order_onestepcheckout_giftwrap_amount</field>
</ignore>

<ignore>
   <field>salesrule_coupon_onestepcheckout_is_popup</field>
</ignore>

          ...
        </field_rules>
       </source>
```

Then run:

> ./magento migrate:data path/to/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/config.xml

But I have got the same message again.

Could you prompt me where I wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

It needs istead

```
<field>sales_flat_order_onestepcheckout_order_comment</field>
```

use

```
<field>sales_flat_order.onestepcheckout_order_comment</field>
```